# How to serve different css file according to user type with node/express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to customize website for user type. Each user type (admin, client...etc) has its own css file. What the best way ?
Add a middleware for auth, and then a routing to the file ?

```
router.get('/mystyle/:user/style.css', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile("mycssfile"+user+".css")
})
```

Comment: You can set a static directory, then use it as you want!!

Comment: Can i do something like this or is it a bad practice ? router.get('/contracts/:contract/style.css', function (req, res) {
    const {contract} = req.params;
    res.sendFile(`mydir/styles/${contract}.css`)
})

Comment: I don't know if it is bad practice but I found it easy and more clear this way. Perhaps serving static files like this way is kind of a bad practice.